# How to enable strict null check for vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

As Typescript introduces strict null check for dynamic runtime errors, it would be great if enabled. I couldn't find any docs or guidelines on how to enable it.

How do I enable strict null check inside VSCode ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> couldn't find any docs or guidelines on how to enable it.

Just use `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions`. E.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {"strictNullChecks":true}
}
```

Comment: As one starting out in TypeScript, I have no idea what this is, where to put it, or how to use it. [Here is the current documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). In short, put ``tsconfig.json`` in the root of your project. Note: I had to restart VS Code before I started seeing the file's effects (I didn't have a ``tsconfig.json`` previously).

Comment: I need a playground not a project, why I just need to setup any configs or some sheet like this, how to pass it to compiler directly?